# convert any image types to webp format using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, webp

I'm using `react-dropzone` package to add images to my app. and in my app i need to send the images to a firebase server. but before i do that i needed to handle image conversions.

so i saw this tutorial on youtube that shows how to convert images to webp format in javascript. but i can't integrate it with my react app.

can anyone please show me how to do just that?

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [text, setText] = useState(
    "Drag and Drop or click here to upload Images"
  );
  const [drag, setDrag] = useState(false);
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      "image/*": [],
    },
    maxFiles: 9,
    onDragEnter: () => {
      setText("drag your images in here");
      setDrag(true);
    },

    onDragLeave: () => {
      setText(
        files.length == 0
          ? "Drag and Drop or click here to upload Images"
          : "Edit your Image..."
      );
      setDrag(false);
    },

    onDrop: (acceptedFiles) => {
      setText("Edit your Image...");
      setDrag(false);
      
      const newFiles = acceptedFiles.map((file) => {
        return Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        });
      });

      if (files.length < 9) {
        setFiles((prev) => [...prev, ...newFiles]);

        files.map((file) => {
          newFiles.forEach((newFile) => {
            if (newFile.name == file.name) {
              alert(newFile.name + " is a duplicate file");

              setFiles(
                files,
                files.filter((val) => val !== newFile)
              );
            }
          });
        });
      } else if (acceptedFiles.length >= 9) {
        alert("select maximum of 9 images");
      } else {
        alert("maximum images to be selected is 9");
      }
    },
  });
```

if there is any packages or methods i appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Image conversion is something you do server side, you shouldn't try to convert the file front-end side...
consider implementing a middleware between firebase and your app, even a basic express server would do

Comment: i'm using Next JS. so how can i use it on `_app.js` file?

Comment: the `_app.js` is the app "root" component, it's technically still a front-end part of your app and is generally used to add custom behaviors to your app, as per the documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app 

If you want to create a middleware you have to create an API handler, check the Next.js doc: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction 

I would suggest reading Next.js documentation and depply understand how it works before doing something like image conversion. 
Once you have that clear, use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-conversion

Comment: yeah i was meant to write the api folder. any ways the package you referred only compresses but doesn't convert to webp format

Answer (score -1):

If the images are supposed to be uploaded to a server to be shown to other users, it's probably best to leave the conversion to server-side code. The server would have to verify the validity of the file anyway.

That being said, modern browsers offer a variety of methods to work with graphics, which can be used to preform the conversion. Here's one way to do this:

```js
/**
 * Convert between any image formats the browser supports
 * @param {Blob} source A Blob (or File) containing the image to convert
 * @param {string} type The MIME type of the target format
 * @returns {Promise<Blob>} The converted image
 */
async function convert(source, type) {
    let image = await createImageBitmap(source);

    let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(image.width, image.height);
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    let result = await canvas.convertToBlob({ type });

    image.close();
    return result;
}
```

This requires a compatible browser. First of all, the browser needs to support WebP, which most browsers do. Second of all, it needs to support `OffscreenCanvas`, which excludes Safari (as of January 2023). In that case, you can use the following method, which does not work in WebWorkers:

```js
/**
 * Convert between any image formats the browser supports
 * @param {Blob} source A Blob (or File) containing the image to convert
 * @param {string} type The MIME type of the target format
 * @returns {Promise<Blob>} The converted image
 */
async function convertLegacy(source, type) {
    let image = await createImageBitmap(source);

    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
            if (blob != null) {
                resolve(blob);
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Failed to convert file"));
            }
        }, type, 1);
    });

    image.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i'm using firebase as a server. so do i have to create node server for the conversion?

Comment: also i'm on next js 13. is there a way i can use the `imagemin-webp` package inside next js api folder?

Comment: A Node server is not needed for the conversation, but if you want to upload the images to some kind storage you will probably want a server that verifies the uploaded files are actually WebP images. Firebase appears to support Next.js server side API routes, so you won't need a seperate server.

Comment: if you provide me with an example that solves my problem it would be great

Comment: `imagemin-webp` is an `imagemin` plugin, which is intended to compress your static assets. If you want to convert images server-side, you'll probably need a different image conversion library.

Comment: What are you planning to use these images for?

Comment: im making a blog app with multiple images input. and i want to post that input image array to filrebase storage. im using `react-dropezone` for the image input. what i wanted was when the user drag or selects images i needed to convert to webp automatically.

Comment: i'm gonna use it inside next/image

Comment: Next.js image optimization functionality, which `next/image` uses, will automatically convert images to types supported by the browser. This can also be configured further: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#acceptable-formats

Comment: so i just have to compress it normally?

Comment: I don't actually know much about Next.js, but it seems like Next.js exposed some API endpoints that can fetch, convert and optimize images, which `next/image` hooks into. You can still convert or optimize the image upfront to save on storage.

Comment: how can i do it in react?